# Issues inserting parent ID into autoform with meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am having issues with inserting a parent id in autoform with meteor. I am using the autoform hook:

```
Template.NewLecture.onRendered( function(){

    AutoForm.hooks({
        insertLectureForm: {
            insert: {
                method: function( doc ) {
                    doc.courseId = Template.parentData(1)._id;
                    return doc;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The Template.parentData(1)._id properly returns the correct ID but it doesn't seem to save into the document. This is the template:

```
    <template name="NewLecture">
        <div class="new-lecture-container">
            {{> quickForm collection='Lectures' id='insertLectureForm' type="insert" class="new-lecture-form"}}
        </div>
    </template>
```

This is the schema:

```
LectureSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Lecture",
        optional: true
    },
    courseId: {
        type: String,
        label: "CourseId",
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
        optional: true
    }
});

Lectures.attachSchema(LectureSchema);
```

What exactly am I missing here? The lecture inserts fine except the courseId is black. If I am using the autoform hooks, to set the courseId value, how should I be setting it in the schema to accept that? Thanks!

EDIT: I have not solved it, but the problem appears to be that Template.parentData(1)._id does not return the same thing inside the insert method as inside the onRender section. Using this new hook:

```
Template.NewLecture.onRendered( function(){
    console.log(Template.parentData(1))

    AutoForm.hooks({
        insertLectureForm: {
            before: {
                insert: function( doc ) {
                    doc.courseId = Template.parentData(1)._id;
                    console.log(Template.parentData(0))
                    console.log(Template.parentData(1))
                    console.log(Template.parentData(2))
                    console.log(Template.parentData(3))
                    console.log(doc)
                    return doc;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I get this output:
[image]
So clearly the first and third console.logs do not match here. How can I either pass in or retrieve the contents of the first console log within that hook?

Comment: Try once removing `autoValue` option.Also are you sure about that `method : function` ?? Try once with `before: {
                insert function( doc ) {`

Comment: Let me know if neither of them works

Answer (score 1):

```
 {{#autoForm collection="Lectures" id="someID"  class="default-form form-horizontal" type="inser"}}
  {{>afQuickField name='courseId' type="hidden" value=helper}}    
{{/autoForm}}

Template.NewLecture.helpers({
  helper:function(){
   return this._id
  }
})
```

Comment: I see where you are going, but I get the error: Exception in template helper: TypeError: Template.instance(...).parentData is not a function.

Comment: what exactly is `Template.parentData(1)._id` , I mean how did you assign a value to it ??

Comment: I use this to display the already existing lectures: Template.AdminLectureList.helpers({
    Lectures: function() {
        return Lectures.find({courseId: this._id});
    }
}); And used this template helper:     {{> NewLecture courseId = _id }}

Comment: Then , I guess you will have the data in `this` inside the helper

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sai! So the solution is that you have to keep passing your parent id down through the helpers like this:

```
<template name="AdminLectureList">
    {{> NewLecture courseId = _id }}
</template>

<template name="NewLecture">
    <div class="new-lecture-container">
        {{> quickForm collection='Lectures' id='insertLectureForm' courseId=courseId type="insert" class="new-lecture-form"}}
    </div>
</template>

Template.NewLecture.onRendered( function(){
    AutoForm.hooks({
        insertLectureForm: {
            before: {
                insert: function( doc ) {
                    doc.courseId = Template.parentData(0).courseId;
                    return doc;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly , you got it